# How to make 2 pictureboxes invisible if 2 images match

Tags: c#

I am doing a memory matching game in c#
when the user matches 2 images i want them to disappear or make them invisible 
i am still new to coding and this is what i did so far but the images wont be invisible

```
    private void apple1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apple1.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
        bool condition = true;

        if (apple1.Image==apple2.Image)
        {
            apple1.Visible = false;
            apple2.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    private void apple2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apple2.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
    }
```

Comment: Pretty standard trap when using Properties.Resources.  Every time you use *apple* you get a **new** bitmap.  It is always different from the previous one.  You must use Properties.Resources.apple only once in your code.  Do so in the constructor to set a variable of type Image.  And be nice and call its Dispose() method in the FormClosed event.

Comment: First, load the images into an array and assign them from there - as is, your code is leaking resources. Second, my crystal ball says you want `condition` to track whether it is the first or second click?  If so dont declare it inside that event handler.  Third, *nothing is working* is a horrible problem description

Comment: In addition to the leaking issue: You can't compare images (or any other reference variables) like that. Instead you need to store the source names, maybe in the pbox.Tag and then compare the strings.

Comment: I agree with Taw; compare tags. Or think of it as comparing *tiles*, not images; the image is just a representation.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `apple1.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;` Note that a copy of the value (Image) of the `Properties.Resources.apple` is set to `apple1.Image`, same thing happens when you assign to  `apple2.Image`, so although visually they seem to have the same image, but they are pointing to different images (in memory).

You may do one of following:

1-Set your images to a dictionary and then load `apple1.Image` and `apple2.Image` from it:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> Images = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

Images.Add("apple", Properties.Resources.apple);
Image apple = Properties.Resources.apple;

private void apple1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    apple1.Image = Images["apple"];

    if (apple1.Image==apple2.Image)
    {
        apple1.Visible = false;
        apple2.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void apple2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    apple2.Image = Images["apple"];
}
```

2-Just use another property to compare equality:

```
private void apple1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    apple1.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
    apple1.Tag = "apple";

    if ((string)apple1.Tag==(string)apple2.Tag)
    {
        apple1.Visible = false;
        apple2.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void apple2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    apple2.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
    apple2.Tag = "apple";
}
```

Comment: This will result in Resource leaks as others have suggested. Every time `.apple` is referenced it's loading yet another Image. Ideally the code needs to store all of the Resources in a `Dictionary` and then look them up later.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell You are right, Thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: Is it still a memory leak since C# is managed or just considered one?

Comment: i did exactly the same and its working but the thing is i have a time of 5 seconds before the timer finishes the images are visible to the user after that they are hidden.  what happened is the 2 images were hidden before the 5 seconds when all images were visible.

Comment: well you may put the comparison method in your timer, instead of click event of image

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you'll need to store all of the Resources just once. Here is a possible example:

```
class MyForm
{
    private Dictionary<String, Image> images = new Dictionary<String, Image>();

    public void Init()
    {
         images["apple"] = Properties.Resources.apple;       
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach(var item in myDictionary.Values)
        {
           item.Dispose();
        }  
    }

    private void apple1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apple1.Image = images["apple"];
        bool condition = true;

        if (apple1.Image==apple2.Image)
        {
            apple1.Visible = false;
            apple2.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    private void apple2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apple2.Image = images["apple"];
    }
}
```