# How to make the image visible for the user before it becomes invisible?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a memory matching game so far I managed to make the cards flip but what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on image1 it shows the image and then the user clicks on image2 what happens on this point is they both become invisible before showing image2. the whole point is to show image1 and then show image2 compare their tag if they match then they become invisible.
examples on how to do this will be appreciated.
this is the code for each picture box and I have 12 picture box.

```
private void picApple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  picApple.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
  if (uncoveredCard1 == null)
  {
    uncoveredCard1 = picApple;
  }
  else if (uncoveredCard1 != null && uncoveredCard2 == null)
  {
    uncoveredCard2 = picApple;
  }
  if (uncoveredCard1 != null && uncoveredCard2 != null)
  {
    if (uncoveredCard1.Tag == uncoveredCard2.Tag)
    {
      uncoveredCard1 = null;
      uncoveredCard2 = null;
      picApple.Visible = false;
      wrdApple.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
      showCard.Start();
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Same comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602611/how-to-make-2-pictureboxes-invisible-if-2-images-match#comment94067745_53602611) Same basic question, different day

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow i will keep asking until i figure out how to do it and understand every single line i put

Comment: @CutieLaft StackOverflow's purpose isn't to help you understand the code that you didn't write or spam questions. I believe that your question has been fully answered. Read documentation on language/technology you work in and carefully analyze your problem and solution. Good luck on your path.

Comment: Wanting to learn and comprehensive understanding is a good thing. But the point was that **3** people mentioned that your app is leaking resources - perhaps quite badly given the nature of the game.  Two days later, the issue remains. You wont learn much by ignoring the advice you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect, there is `if` instead of `else if`, so your 2nd card gets its picture, and then it's hidden immediately.

Try this:

```
private void picApple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  picApple.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
  if (uncoveredCard1 == null)
  {
    uncoveredCard1 = picApple;
  }
  else if (uncoveredCard1 != null && uncoveredCard2 == null)
  {
    uncoveredCard2 = picApple;
  }
  else if (uncoveredCard1 != null && uncoveredCard2 != null)
  {
    if (uncoveredCard1.Tag == uncoveredCard2.Tag)
    {
      uncoveredCard1 = null;
      uncoveredCard2 = null;
      picApple.Visible = false;
      wrdApple.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
      showCard.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i tried and it did work but what happened is i clicked the 1st image it showed, i clicked the 2nd image it showed but then i have to click again to make them invisible.

Comment: You haven't described all aspects of your problem. By combining my answer the answer by LarsTech, your problem is solved. I see already that you will have a problem if your cards don't match.